# OnClick function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to use buttons in my HTML to track. I have the Javascript code in place that does what I need. However, for each button it is all tracking in the top section. I am not sure what I need to change in my Javascript code to be able to track clicks for each of the buttons in my HTML.

```
<div id="clientAssist">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h2>Client Assist</h2>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <div class="space">
            <form name="form1" method="post" action="">
                <p>
                    <label for="name">Client: </label>
                    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Client name">
                </p>
                <p>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        var clicks = 0;
                        function onClick() {
                        clicks += 1;
                        document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
                        };
                    </script>
                    <button type="button" onClick="onClick()">30 min Tracker</button>
                <p>Clicks: <a id="clicks">0</a></p>
                </p>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="projects">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h2>Projects</h2>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <div class="space"  >
            <form name="form2" method="post" action="">
                <p>
                    <label for="name">Project: </label>
                    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Project name">
                </p>
                <p>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        var track = 0;
                        function onClick() {
                        track += 1;
                        document.getElementById("track").innerHTML = track;
                        };
                    </script>
                    <button type="button" onClick="onClick()">30 min Tracker</button>
                <p>Clicks: <a id="track">0</a></p>
                </p>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="myLearning">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h2>MyLearning</h2>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <div class="space"  >
            <form name="form3" method="post" action="">
                <p>
                    <label for="name">Description: </label>
                    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Description">
                </p>
                <p>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        var clicks = 0;
                        function onClick() {
                        clicks += 1;
                        document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
                        };
                    </script>
                    <button type="button" onClick="onClick()">30 min Tracker</button>
                <p>Clicks: <a id="clicks">0</a></p>
                </p>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why is your scripting intermixed with your HTML like that? It would make things much clearer, cleaner, and easier if you arranged things properly. Also, each `ID` used for an element should be unique-- you can't have multiple elements with `id='clicks'`.

Comment: Sorry, but your question is unclear.  Please state exactly what you're trying to achieve, because at the moment, I haven't got a clue.  (What I will say though is that you're creating multiple functions called `onClick` (which is not a great name) so only the last one will exist)

Comment: are you trying to make it so each button tracks its own clicks or that all buttons track the same clicks. ie, button 1 and 2 are clicked once. should the button display 2 or 1 on each of them

Answer (score 1):

To save your data you can use a raw object as a map.

Each button need to have a unique id to know which button has been clicked.

The `onClick` function can have the clicked button as parameter and use the button id to save the click in the map

```js
// Map <string, number>
var clicks = {};


function onClick(element){
    var key = element.id;
    
    // Init the value if not here
    if (!clicks[key]){
         clicks[key] = 0;   
    }
    
    clicks[key]++;
    
    //Update the content of the next 'a' tag
    document.querySelector ('#'+key+" + p a").innerHTML = clicks[key];
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="client" onClick="onClick(this)">30 min Tracker</button>
<p>Clicks: <a class="clicks">0</a></p>

<button type="button" id="project" onClick="onClick(this)">30 min Tracker</button>
<p>Clicks: <a class="clicks">0</a></p>
```

Comment: I tried using this code above here is what I tried in JSFiddle, and it is still not working. I must be missing something. https://jsfiddle.net/xhL74n1x/

Comment: it's because you need to add this code in the `head` tag of your html, see: https://jsfiddle.net/5cdrp79u/ .On the right you can see `No wrap - in <head>`. Also you don't have to put a script tag in the javascript part of jsfiddle

Comment: Excellent!! Thank you so much!! My other part of my problem was the order of my JS files. But all works now! Thank you for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to refactor your code a bit. You can loop through the elements setting a 'click' event listener to each. It would need to be implemented using a closure so that all the event listeners exist after the outer function is returned. If you do not, only the last event listener will stay bound.

Alternatively you can use jQuery. For example:

```
        // create list of cats
        for (var cat of cats){
            list.append("<li class=\"list\">" + cat.name +"</li>");
        };
        // on click hooks the event to all list elements 
        list.on("click", ".list", function(){
            // do something 
        });
```

Comment: jQuery has not been tagged.

Comment: @JamieBarker it's an alternative.. can't you read

Comment: I can read. Maybe if I say it a different way: **The poster is not using jQuery**. So, maybe you might want to, I don't know, re-factor the code into vanilla JavaScript? If you need help with that, try [this helpful website](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/).

Comment: The only person here that should have issues with my answer is the poster then. Not you. I told him/her how to do it in vanilla and offered a much simpler way using jQuery. **The poster** can decide if he wants to use it or not.

Comment: More and less. Of course the poster is the one deciding if he will use your proposed alternative, and since he did not state clearly that he wants only javascript your answer kind of stands, but answers containing only jquery code to a javascript-only question *are* off topic.

Comment: What Felix said. You're welcome to give jQuery in your answer, but at least give the JavaScript code that your jQuery is an alternative to

Comment: OK. You guys are right.. I'll be sure to think about that next time.

Comment: Ok, I tried using the example with javascript and it is still not working. I've checked and double checked my code and it looks like it is matching yours. Please advise. JSFiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/xhL74n1x/

Comment: Here is my link to what I tried in JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/xhL74n1x/

Comment: in your js file you have `document.querySelector('#'+key+" + p a").innerHTML = clicks[key];` but the anchor with class `.clicks` is not a child of the `'#'+key'` element.